# Windows service running under network credentials doesn't autostart

Tags: windows, service, credentials

I have a Subversion Server running as a resident service on a Windows XP Pro machine.  That service needs to access a secure network fileshare, so I used the Services->Properties->Log On tab to tell the service to run as a user who has access to the target fileshare.  That works out fine until the machine restarts, when the service fails to autostart.

I am able to start it manually by logging in, going back to that Services->Properties->Log On tab and reconfiming the explicit credentials.

1. Do I have to manually start this
   service under alternate credentials
   every time the machine reboots?
2. Is there something else I can do to
   make sure that my Subversion server
   service autostarts with proper access 
   to authenticate against this network share?

Answer (score 1):

You have the service set to 'Automatic' in services.msc, right?

Comment: yes, the service is set to Automatic; my guess was that some security policy might be disallowing the service to automatically start with cached credentials...

Comment: You could put 'net start serviceshortname' in one of your startup scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Can you see any error messages in the event viewer when your service is trying to start up (under Application, System, or Security)?

Answer (score 1):

Make the service dependent on some other networking service. So it won't start before there is network access.

something like:

```
sc config YourService depend= rpcss
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem to this; a service is running quite happily using a service account created in AD. I have to carry out some maintenance on the service, so shut it down, then when I start it up again, it fails with a "The service did not start due to a logon failure" error. Re-entering the credentials in the services.msc snap-in fixes the issue, until the next time.

Is there a way to make the password "stick"?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this requires that the account being used for the service needs to be give the Log On As A Service right?  See [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160219223808/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/ablock/archive/2008/09/18/setting-the-properties-the-log-on-as-a-service-and-allow-log-on-locally.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

- While setting up windows service you can edit its properties and set the `Log On` user. At that moment appropriate rights should be granted automatically, giving you rights to run your service. However those permissions are not sticky and you would need to repeat this each time server restarts.
- However you can use `Administrative Tools / Local Security Policy / Local Policies / User Rights Assignment` to add user to "Log on as a service". This should grant given user permanent rights to restart the windows service.